# Matlab optimization: record data over iterations

Tags: matlab, optimization, output, pass-by-reference

**Is it possible using Matlab for optimization to record data from one iteration to the next with a function m-file containing only the [Output function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/output-function.html)?**

The provided [Example](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/output-functions.html#brjhnpu) shows that the optimization function needs be called from within a "runOptimization"-function where also the nested output function resides.

```
function [history,searchdir] = runOptimization

% Set up shared variables with OUTFUN
history.x = [];
history.fval = [];
searchdir = [];

% call optimization
x0 = [-1 1];
options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'OutputFcn',@outfun,... 

% nested output function
function stop = outfun(x,optimValues,state)
    stop = false;
    switch state
    % ... store history and search directions over all iterations
```

Also [this site](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/output-functions.html#bsgpq6q-31) claims that, if you want your output function to record data from one iteration to the next, you should write a single file that does the following:

- Contains the output function as a nested function.
- Calls the optimization function.

However, I was wondering if it is possible to create a m-file that contains just the output function and uses extra parameters `history` and `searchdir` as input.

I tried it with the following anonymous function approach, where the shared variables `history` and `searchdir` are declared "outside" in my main m-file (not global). And for the objective function and the output function I use seperate m-files.

```
% main m-file
% Set up shared variables with OUTFUN
history.x = [];
history.fval = [];
searchdir = [];

outf = @(x,optimValues,state)outfun(x,optimValues,state,history,searchdir);

objective = @(x) objective_function(x,y,h);

x0 = [-1 1];
x = fmincon(objective,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],[],options);
```

Though, every time the output function returns, the shared variables are empty again. Is there another solution instead of global variables, something like pass by reference instead of copies as arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three solutions, each one worse than the other:

**1. Using handle classes.**

Main file:

```
clear all
history= histclass;
outf= @(x,optimValues,state)outfun3(x,optimValues,state,history);
objective= @(x) x(1)^2+x(2)^4; % just for example
options = optimset('OutputFcn',outf);
x0 = [-1 1];
x = fmincon(objective,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],[],options);
disp(history.x);
disp(history.fval);
```

`histclass` definition:

```
classdef histclass < handle
    properties 
        x= [];
        fval= [];
    end
    methods 
        function add(obj,newx,newfval)
            obj.x= [obj.x; newx];
            obj.fval= [obj.fval  newfval];
        end
    end
end
```

Output function:

```
function stop = outfun3(x,optimValues,state,history)
    stop = false;
    history.add(x,optimValues.fval);
end
```

**2. Using `evalin`.**

Main file:

```
history= struct('x',[],'fval',[]); % create the structure with empty fields
history(1)= []; % create the empty structure array with the specified fields
add_history= @(x,fval,varname)evalin('base',...
    ['history(end+1)= struct(''x'',' mat2str(x) ',''fval'',' num2str(fval) ')']);
outf= @(x,optimValues,state)outfun(x,optimValues,state,add_history);
objective= @(x) x(1)^2+x(2)^4; % just for example
options = optimset('OutputFcn',outf);
x0 = [-1 1];
x = fmincon(objective,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],[],options);
disp([history.x]);
```

Output function:

```
function stop = outfun(x,optimValues,state,add_history)
    stop = false;
    add_history(x,optimValues.fval);
end
```

**3. Using files**

Main file:

```
clear all
history= struct('x',[],'fval',[]); % create the structure with empty fields
history(1)= []; % create the empty structure array with the specified fields
save('history.mat')
objective= @(x) x(1)^2+x(2)^4; % just for example
options = optimset('OutputFcn',@outfun2);
x0 = [-1 1];
x = fmincon(objective,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],[],options);
load('history.mat')
disp([history.x]);
```

Output function:

```
function stop = outfun2(x,optimValues,state)
    stop = false;
    load('history.mat','history')
    history(end+1)= struct('x',x,'fval',optimValues.fval);
    save('history.mat')
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So you suggest the "cleanest" approach would be to use what Mathworks suggests: A nested function that contains the output function?

Comment: Yes, I do. Using handle classes seems to be the least ugly solution, but it is too slow